# how to bring up the activity that exists in the activity back-stack in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Suppose I have an Activity named `ActivityA` and another Activity named `ActivityB`. In each one I have a button that opens another Activity when it is clicked. I want to do following work when button is clicked:

```
check if there is an existing type of the target Activity in the activity back-stack or not, if there is, bring that Activity to the top and if not create new Intent and then go to that Activity.
How can I implement this?
```

Thanks.

Comment: try add launch mode in the manifest for single instance

Comment: Yes for Zach's comment, and the doc is [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

Comment: @ZachBublil that does not solve all my problem. I want to hold another  activity in the back-stack and just want to bring target activity to front.

Comment: @Weekend please read my comment.

Comment: As I said, try the launch mode option in the AndroidManifest. In short, it defines how your activity would be launched - single instance makes your app bring the activity to front if the back stack is already has an instance of this activity or create an instance if not.

Comment: As Zac said add the following line while declaring Activity in Manifest, android:launchMode="singleInstance"

Comment: Use of special launch mode is all wrong here. That isn't what OP wants and using special launch modes is the wrong approach anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Simple.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

This does exactly what you want. If there is already an instance of `TargetActivity` in the task stack, that instance will be rearranged and brought to the top (front) of the stack. If there is no existing instance of `TargetActivity`, Android will create a new instance and put that on the top of the stack.